# How do I wrap a <div> around text like smartphone text bubbles?

Tags: html, css, text, format

You know how smartphone text bubbles vary in width depending on the length of the text yet has a maximum width where it forces the text to begin a new line?

Similar to that, how do I make a div in css do just that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block;` with a `max-width`

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum delectus.</p></div>

<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
```

Alternatively, if stacking is required

```css
div {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum delectus.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it however is there a way to make the divs come horizontally than be side by side?

Comment: @MiniSiniPi Did you mean “vertically”? Simply add a `<br/>`.

Comment: Yep., see update. Using floats instead of `inline-block`. Frankly though it's not normally done this way...it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah vertically, sorry about that, thanks you've helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
p.bubble
{
 position: relative;
 display:inline-block;
 width:auto;
  height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 100px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 8px solid #666;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 border-radius: 30px;
}

p.bubble:before
{
 content: ' ';
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 left: 30px;
 top: 100px;
 border: 25px solid;
 border-color: #666 transparent transparent #666;
}

p.bubble:after
{
 content: ' ';
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 left: 38px;
 top: 100px;
 border: 15px solid;
 border-color: #fff transparent transparent #fff;
}
```

```html
<p class="bubble">Chris: Hey dude, how are you?</p>
```

BTW: It took me 2 seconds to google it.